# How to get a full android app UID programmatically?

Tags: android, adb, uid

**Edit 10 Apr 2020**

I may have misnamed what we are looking for. It may actually be the *linux user name* of the installed app, rather than its UID. So how should we get that programmatically?

**Original question below**

When we use `adb shell ps` even on a non rooted android device, it returns process info where the UID comes in the form `u0_xxxx` where `x` represents some arbitrary digits in hex (except for system/root processes).

For example

> u0_a464      31481   894 5015336  69200 0                   0 S com.example.app_uid_checker

In this example app_uid_checker is my app in user space. When trying to obtain the UID programmatically, though, I get 10464 (the decimal representation of a464), and without the `u0` prefix.

I tried

1. package manager's getApplicationInfo()
2. activity manager's getAllRunningProcess()
3. android.os.Process.myUid()

(following suggestions in [this post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123434/obtain-the-linux-uid-of-an-android-app). They all return 10464. How can I get the "full" UID? (for want of a better term, I'm not sure what the u0_a464 version of the UID should be called, as compared to the 10464 version)).

Even if we can programmatically use `adb shell ps` I think it may not be a good way, as adb needs developer mode to be enabled.

Comment: I think this is a misunderstanding. the `u0_xxxx` notation is not the UID but the user name. Therefore your actual question is `How do I get the Linux user name from it's UID on Android?`.

Comment: Oh! Is that what it is? linux user name .. hmm, so `adb shell ps' actually lists the linux user name not the uid? Then how do we get that programmatically? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23454000/how-to-get-username-using-uid-on-android seems to indicate there isn't a simple way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the geteuid(2) and getpwuid(3) to retrieve the data, as the JVM does not expose it.

```cpp
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_example_GetUser_getUser(JNIEnv* env) {
    uid_t uid = geteuid();
    struct passwd *user;
    if (uid == -1)
        return NULL;
    user = getpwuid(uid);
    return env->NewStringUTF(user->pw_name);
}
```

Full working project: https://gitlab.com/hackintosh5/getuser